# Phalcon MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, phalcon

`php7.0`, `Phalcon 3.2`, `MongoDB 3.2.14`

I want to connect to MongoDB, but in Phalcon documentation only about connection via MongoClient() and working with it. I have php7.0 and MongoClient() is deprecated in it. How I can correctly use `\MongoDB\Driver\Manager()` with Phalcon?
In `services.php` I wrote this:

```
/**
* MongoDB connection
*/
$di->set( "mongo", function () {
       $config = $this->getConfig();

        $db_string = sprintf( 'mongodb://%s:%s/%s', $config->mongodb->host, $config->mongodb->port, $config->mongodb->database );

        if( isset( $config->mongodb->user ) AND isset( $config->mongodb->password ) ) {
            $db_string = sprintf( 'mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s',
                $config->mongodb->user,
                (string)$config->mongodb->password,
                $config->mongodb->host,
                (string)$config->mongodb->port,
                $config->mongodb->database );
       }

        try {
            return new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager( $db_string );
        } catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
            die( 'Failed to connect to MongoDB '.$e->getMessage() );
        }
    },
    true
);
```

It works. But in models there are errors. In `app/models/User.php` I wrote:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Collection;

class User extends Collection
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSource('users');
    }
}
```

And in controller:

```
class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo User::count();
    }
}
```

In browser I have this:

```
Call to undefined method ::selectcollection()
#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Collection::_getGroupResultset(Array, Object(User), Object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager))
#1 /var/www/testing/app/controllers/IndexController.php(8): Phalcon\Mvc\Collection::count()
#2 [internal function]: IndexController->indexAction()
#3 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->callActionMethod(Object(IndexController), 'indexAction', Array)
#4 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->_dispatch()
#5 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#6 /var/www/testing/public/index.php(42): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#7 {main}
```

How I can do it correclty? :) sorry for my English, I from Russia :)

My original question is [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687194/phalcon-mongodb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Incubator` package: https://github.com/phalcon/incubator

See example of using here -
 https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Db/Adapter#mongodbclient